# C programming - integer/long to string representation

Tags: c, arrays, printf, long-integer

I'm just reading "C Interfaces and Implementations". There are some really interesting concepts described in the book. The code is quite ugly sometimes (in my opinion), but now I got a question regarding conversion of an integer/long to a string (char array). What is described in the book is:

```
const char *Atom_int(long n) {
    char str[43];
    char *s = str + sizeof str;
    unsigned long m;
    if (n == LONG_MIN)
        m = LONG_MAX + 1UL;
    else if (n < 0)
        m = -n;
    else
        m = n;
    do
        *--s = m%10 + '0';
    while ((m /= 10) > 0);
    if (n < 0)
        *--s = '-';

    return Atom_new(s, str + sizeof str - s);
}
```

As there's no description why that function is used the way it is...I wonder why it's not just something simple like:

```
const char *Atom_int(long n)
{
    char str[43];
    char *s = str;
    sprintf(str, "%ld", n);

    return Atom_new(s, str + sizeof str - s);
}
```

Is there any difference? Anything I missed about my "simple" approach using sprintf that could cause a different result than the function from the book? I mean, if it's just to show how one could convert a long to a string not using ltoa/sprintf/..., nice. But it's unnecessary complex if that's the only reason,...

Comment: You shouldn't expect builtin functions in the book `C Interfaces and Implementations` which defeat the purpose of the book.

Comment: My copy of the book has `return Atom_new(s, (str + sizeof str) - s)` instead of `return s`.

Comment: If that function really is 1:1 from the book, definitively get another book! It returns a pointer with an then-invalid value!

Comment: Yes, you're right. There's also no "printf" to print the value. That's been only for testing purpose, was well as removing the return Atom_new...

Comment: @inzanez :  By stating that the code was from a book, but actually modifying it, and in the process breaking it, you are misrepresenting the book in a manner that is severely detrimental to the reputation of the author.  If I were you I'd edit the question so that the code is *exactly* as that in the book.  If I were the author I'd be pretty angry right now.

Comment: @Clifford good point, just corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were two major problems with the original code you posted for both functions:

- The `str` array is not `'\0'` terminated, invoking undefined behavior when passed to `printf`.
- Returning a pointer `s` to an array with automatic storage `str` is also incorrect.  Dereferencing this return value will invoke undefined behavior as well.

Regarding your questions, the purpose of the first function is to show the implementation of an integer to string converter.  Using `sprintf` defeats this purpose.  Note how the author handles the subtile case of `INT_MIN`: computing `-n` would invoke undefined behavior because of the integer overflow on most systems, eventhough the result would be correct on all modern systems.  But complete conformance to the Standard os a difficult art: his solution assumes 2s complement and will fail otherwise.

Here is an improved solution with the same prototype. It is more portable, does not need to special case `LONG_MIN`, makes fewer divisions and modulo operations.

```
const char *Atom_int(long n) {
    char str[43];
    char *s = str + sizeof str;
    unsigned long m;
    if (n < 0)
        m = (unsigned long)-(n + 1) + 1;
    else
        m = n;

    while (m >= 10) {
        *--s = m % 10 + '0';
        m /= 10;
    }
    *--s = m + '0';
    if (n < 0)
        *--s = '-';

    return Atom_new(s, str + sizeof str - s);
}
```

Also note that your proposed alternative is incorrect: you pass the wrong length to `Atom_new()`.  You should pass the number of bytes returned by `sprintf` or `snprintf`.  Here is an improved version:

```
const char *Atom_int(long n) {
    char str[43];
    return Atom_new(str, snprintf(str, sizeof str, "%ld", n));
}
```

Comment: Agree, the first function doesn't 0 terminate. Both functions return a pointer to automatic storage. Ugly. Apart from that, just looking at the "long to char array" conversion process: Anything that speaks for this over complex version?

Comment: `snprintf` would be better than `sprintf`

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. So there's no reason to prefer such code over using something like snprintf.

Comment: @inzanez: It is not a matter of style, but plain wrong!

Comment: @inzanez "Both functions return a pointer to automatic storage."

Comment: There is a purpose: not relying on `printf` which might not be available. @Olaf The book says "Atom_int must cope with the asymmetrical range of two’s- complement" and OP didn't copy the original source code which correctly allocates memory.

Comment: @a3f: As OP is expected to provide a [mcve], We have to judge on what he posts, not what else can be found somewhere. Repeating this in your code makes it worse in fact. And the standard does not require an implementation to use asymmetrical signed integer ranges. It does not even enforce a specific encoding, nor all values to be valid. See `limts.h` in the standard.

Comment: @inzanez: it's not really overly complex, it's as complex as the problem requires. It's not like `sprintf` is magic, internally it has code like this. Reasons for preferring this code: it's probably faster, since there's no format string parsing and no locale conformance involved. But again, the basic point here is explaining an algorithm.

Comment: @inzanez: But you tried to relativate this by calling it "ugly". "ugly" means a flaw at worst, but that is - as I wrote - **plain wrong**.

Comment: @inzanez: which is fine, but it's also important to have a solid understanding of how the wheels you use every day are made (and potentially being able to make them yourself if the ones provided for some reason do not fit).

Comment: @Olaf: What I wanted to say is that the author did state that code is twos-complement specific. I don't want someone reading the answer or comments to disparage the book because OP failed to post actual code and context.

Comment: @olaf: Ok, I was a bit unclear describing what I thought maybe. Look at the 'updated' code now, there's no plain wrong. There's no ugly either maybe, but unnecessary complex code _in_my_opinion as the section is not about conversion of long integers into char arrays, but something else. So one could just use already existing functionality instead of reinventing it...

Comment: @a3f: Well, then you should say that. There's more to C than PCs, Server and ARM. Anyway, that's why we have [ask] and require a [mcve]. Actually such incomplete questions should not be answered, but requested to be completed first.

Comment: @a3f: I posted a simpler, more portable solution that handles the asymmetrical range of 2s complement representation. It only assumes a maximum range for the `long` type somewhere around 128 bits.

Comment: You could remove even that limitation by sizing the array like `char str[2+(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(n)+9)/10*4]`; slightly wasteful (4 decimal digits every 10 bits, rounded up, plus the terminator plus the sign), but the calculation can be done at compile time and should be safe.

Comment: @chqrlie I totally agree with your point: "Returning a pointer s to an array with automatic storage str is also incorrect.". Just a question, why doesn't this give any compiler warning. I thought there should be some warning about returning the address of local var when I'm using `CFLAGS="-g -Wall -std=c99 -O3 -pedantic-errors"` - but there isn't. What am I missing?

Comment: @artm: in the original code, the return statement used local variable `s`.  `s` was initialized to point to the end of the automatic array `str` and only updated relatively by successive decrement operations. The compiler does not seem to be smart enough to determine that `s` still points to automatic storage.  In this case it seems doable and it is too bad `gcc` cannot do it, but in the general case it is much more difficult and probably impossible.